# UILabel instead of the default pin on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mapkit, mkmapview

Is it possible to have our own UILabel or some other type of text instead of the default pin in MapKit map on iPhone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend MKAnnotationView, this way you can specify (through the image property) what shows on for each pin, further you can customize the pop up views etc. Heres a reference http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html